# Why Django modelform is submitted with enter key

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I'm using Django modelform and it's submitted by pressing the enter key. This is what I wanted, but I don't know why it works. I didn't add any JS codes related to `keydown` but other codes to practice **Ajax**. Also, I found out that when there's only one input inside the form, it's submitted with the enter key, but my form has two inputs.

What I'm doing is to add a comment on a post like instagram. I used Ajax to create a comment instance.

- models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    parent_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    author = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

- forms.py

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ["parent_post"]
```

- HTML

```
{% for post in posts %}
 <form method="POST" data-id="{{post.id}}" class="d-flex align-items-center w-100 mt-2">
            {% load widget_tweaks %} <!-- this is a django package for easy CSS -->
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.author.errors }}
        {{ form.author|add_class:"form__author"|attr:"placeholder:name" }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper w-100">
        {{ form.content.errors }}
        {{ form.content|add_class:"form__content"|attr:"placeholder:content" }}
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning w-auto">Write</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

- JS (Here I didn't put the codes after getting JSON response from views.py)

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");
forms.forEach((value) => {
  const post_id = Number(value.getAttribute("data-id"));

  value.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents reload, still submits form data but views.py does nothing for this data
    writeComment(post_id);
  });

const requestWrite = new XMLHttpRequest();
const writeComment = (post_id) => {
  const form = document.querySelector(`form[data-id="${post_id}"]`);
  const author = form.querySelector(".form__author");
  const content = form.querySelector(".form__content");

  const url = "/write/";
  if (author.value && content.value) {
    requestWrite.open("POST", url, true);
    requestWrite.setRequestHeader(
      "Content-Type",
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    );
    requestWrite.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        post_id: post_id,
        author: author.value,
        content: content.value,
      })
    );
    author.value = null;
    content.value = null;
  }
};
```

- views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def write(request):
    req = json.loads(request.body)
    post_id = req["post_id"]
    author = req["author"]
    content = req["content"]
    comment = Comment.objects.create(parent_post=get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id), author=author, content=content)

    return JsonResponse({"post_id":post_id, "comment_id":getattr(comment, "id"), "author":author, "content":content})
```

Thank you!

Comment: A <button> inside a <form> triggers submission unless you add `type="button"` to it. Hitting enter anywhere inside the form (except while inside a <textarea>, or while selecting a dropdown suggestion, etc.) will submit the form.

Comment: oh it's submitted even if there were multiple inputs. Thank you! @ChrisG